# I'm trying to add a custom product/price to the Stripe Checkout Page using php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to customise stripe checkout to take a dynamic price from my cart.  To test that I am simply trying to create a product and price within the strip config and then pass that price into the line item.

The code that I am trying keeps telling me that is no such product.  I don't know if I am making a syntax error or if what I am trying is just wrong.  can anyone advise?

```
include './stripe/init.php';
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('API KEY GOES HERE');

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$YOUR_DOMAIN = 'https://www.XXXXX.XX.XX';

$product = \Stripe\Product::create([
  'name' => 'Elearn Product',
]);

$price = \Stripe\Price::create([
  'product' => '{{$product}}',
  'unit_amount' => 1100,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'recurring' => [
    'interval' => 'month',
  ],
]);

$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([



  'line_items' => [[
    'price' => '{{$price}}',
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'payment_method_types' => [
    'card',
   ],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/enrolment-success',
  'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/enrolment-failure',
]);

header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
header("Location: " . $checkout_session->url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the Product and Price IDs like this:

```php
'product' => $product->id,
```

And this:

```php
'price' => $price->id,
```

Also, you can create multiple Prices for one Product, so if you're selling the same thing at different price points you can create the Product once and create many Prices for it instead of creating a new Product each time.